# Sum of product result given by wolfram: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{3i-1}{4i}=2(2)^\frac{1}{3}-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, wolfram-alpha

So according to Wolfram Alpha, the following result holds: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{3i-1}{4i}=2(2)^\frac{1}{3}-1$$

Could someone explain to me how Wolfram Alpha gets this or how to calculate a sum of products like this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We use the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem) for general exponents $r\in \mathbb{C}$ with $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x|>|y|$:
>   $$(x+y)^r=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {r \choose k} x^{r-k} y^k$$
>   with
>   $$\binom{r}{k}=\frac{r(r-1) \cdots (r-k+1)}{k!}$$

We then have that with $m:=1/3$ and $r:=-2/3$:
$$\begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{3i-1}{4i}&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^{k} \left[\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4i}\right]\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^k\prod_{i=1}^{k} \left[1-\frac{m}{i}\right]\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^k (1-m)(1-m/2)\cdots (1-m/k)\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)^k\cdot \frac{(m-1)(m-2)\cdots (m-k)}{k!}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)^k\cdot \frac{r(r-1)\cdots (r-k+1)}{k!}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left[\frac{r(r-1)\cdots (r-k+1)}{k!}\cdot 1^{r-k}\cdot (-3/4)^k\right]-1\\&=(1-3/4)^{-2/3}-1\\&=2\cdot 2^{1/3}-1\end{align}$$
which is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: Thank you. I was studying this in the context of linear b-d chains with immigration. Would there be a closed form solution for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{\lambda(i-1)+\alpha}{\mu i}$ If there is, I will ask another question separately.

Comment: I could try to work it out myself, if the steps are similar to this example.

Comment: Are $\lambda,\alpha$ and $\mu\neq 0$ real numbers? If so the same technique should work, you could reduce the product to one of the form $\prod_{i=1}^k \left[1-\frac{m}{i}\right]$, then use the same reasoning. Be sure though that when you use the generalized binomial theorem that $|x|>|y|$ holds.